# Bootstrap First Grid - Right

Tags: grid, scale

How do I Use grid bootstrap this way?

I want to scale RIGHT panel first, but bootstrap scale MOBILE from LEFT

```
_______________________________________
Bootstrap:
1                 2                 3


I want:
3                 1                 2

_______________________________________
```

PS.
I Want that grid will be in this same position relative to the height

```
___1____           ____2_____          ____3______


NOT

                                       ___3____



___1____             _____2______
```

Comment: I worked it out. Result:
`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>`

Comment: Post your comment as an answer to your question, others can benefit from it then.

Answer (score 0):

try this to make 3 in RIGHT

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">3</div>
```